# How to stop uploading pictures on Google Photos on Pixel 2?

Tags: google-photos, google-pixel, google-pixel-2, 9.0-pie

I've been using Android for 7+ years and now got a Google phone. There are several things I like but one I didn't is that any picture I take on my phone, it is uploaded to my Google Photos account. In the past, I used to create Picasa web albums to share with family.

It is a nice feature in some ways but I've set up albums in Google Photos in the past and now every random picture I take with my phone is uploaded there. I also get a lot of pictures from WhatsApp etc. which I don't want to be merged with Google Photos.

How can I separate phone pictures/albums from Google Photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Photos shows you a prompt when you first open the app. If you press confirm, it will automatically start uploading your photos to the cloud.

You can manage the setting in your Google Photos app.
Open the app and go to *Settings > Back up & sync* and turn it off.